# Magento Search Not working - Only returns results if I search SKU codes

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, index

I have a Magento 2.4.3 installed with `Elasticsearch 7.9` They are on separate servers (but I don't believe that is relevant). The reindexing function runs successfully and I can see the index on the elasticsearch:

```
health status index                 uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .geoip_databases      Pe0O24UMQmuLHIVp_H5Jkw   1   0         42            0     40.1mb         40.1mb
yellow open   magento2_product_1_v2 LE4DUb_6QhmZ1K_E0oyIgA   1   1        727            0     1008kb         1008kb
```

But when I search for anything meaningful in the front end using the Luma theme nothing comes up only if I search using SKUs.

Everything seems to be running just fine, so I just don't know where to look. I have tried all of the usual suggestions on here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the product attributes like "Name", "Description", etc are used in search. Check it under admin panel -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> [edit attribute "name"] -> Storefront Properties tab -> Use in Search = Yes.

Comment: I tried that, and it is set to use in search.

Answer (score 0):

Search pointers to look at  :

1. Attribute set to search and its weight.
2. Where the attributes indexed?
3. Is there any third party modules extending search features.
4. IS Search engine set to elastic search( no option but some modules can be used to override elastic search)
5. Log the request response from and by elastic search adapter and look at the values in the query request.
6. Query elastic search using command to check what all data is int he document.